# Can't get crontab to run shell script

Tags: linux

This seems to be common issue, I've gone through dozens of ask sites with similar issues/questions, but non of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm using Raspberry Pi OS (64 bit) beta test version.

Here's my script, it works perfectly when used outside of crontab, but not in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! screen -list | grep -q "minecraft"; then
  cd /home/pi/minecraft
  screen -S minecraft -d -m java -jar -Xms2G -Xmx7G spigot-1.17.jar nogui
fi
```

I'm using sudo crontab -e but have also tried crontab -e:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I plan on using this script at boot and related scripts throughout the day, but I'm currently just setting it to run a few minutes in the future to test it.

```
05 16 * * * /home/pi/minecraft/scripts/start.sh
```

I'm not getting any sockets in the screen list:

```
screen -list
```

I'm not getting any errors in syslog or in my mailbox, I've tried putting bin/bash, /bin/sh, and sh in front of the path and some other tweaks but nothing is happening.

Comment: `sudo crontab -e` then why don't you check `sudo screen -list`?

Comment: Not showing up there either, would've shown in the minecraft server list anyway.

Comment: What permissions have you given the `start.sh` script?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 159 Jul 19 16:11 /home/pi/minecraft/scripts/start.sh

Comment: add a line `DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY` near the top of the crontab, or in the script.

Comment: Adding `DISPLAY=:0; export DISPLAY` to the crontab did nothing, adding it to the script left the error `/home/pi/minecraft/scripts/start.sh: 3: /home/pi/minecraft/scripts/start.sh: DISPLAY-:1: not found` in my mail

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my crontab path was different, so I had to add this before my commands in crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1/bin
```